# QGIS 'Rasterize vector to raster' failing to create viable raster

Tags: qgis, shapefile, rasterization

I had a DEM (.asc):

[image]
[image]

Which was converted to a shapefile point cloud (see attached below) and I'm trying to convert back to raster within QGIS 3.8.2

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjCedBZJ5Eh4kEKj4AAjcItprRax?e=hPjIX7

The Shapefile loads fine in QGIS, and I can see that points have varying Z values for height
[image]

Using Rasterize (vector to raster) I set up with resolution of 641 matching original DEM

[image]

But all I get is a black to white colour ramp top to bottom as output:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

When you are burning the value of the bid field, you are assigning each pixel a value that goes from 0 I guess to 410880.

[image: 1]

If you want to burn the Z value of the point, you must add a field in the table and populate it with the Z coordinate of each feature.

[image: 2]

Note: for some reason, QGIS never finished saving the layer. Believing that it was the problem that shapefiles have when they weigh more than 2GB, I decided to export the vector layer to geopackage format (incidentally, I invite you to stop using shapefiles). Even so, the file does not occupy more than 59MB, so I don't know what the original problem was.

[image: 3]

With the updated layer, you can proceed to rasterize it by burning the value of the Z field in each pixel.

[image: 4]

The extent of the output layer was calculated based on the extent of the input layer (in the body of the question there were no written values so I can't copy and paste them). Probably because of this, some artifacts occurred in the output raster.

[image: 5]